# C# cant runt on prompt with <

Tags: c#, command-prompt, calling-convention

So, I've written a program which takes data from an file and process it and presents the answer. I got an error that's a bit confusing. If I call the program in the command prompt as follows: test.exe < indata.txt nothing happens, if I skip the < i.e. calls the program as: test.txt indata.txt it works fine. It also works if I call it with double in data files. Like: test.txt < indata.txt indata.txt. It's like the < token skips the following entry.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int revolter = 0;
    string[] buffer_array = new string[2000];
    string path = "./";
     

    if (args.Length == 0)
    {
        string read_string = System.Console.ReadLine();
        buffer_array = read_string.Split(' ');
    }
    else
    {
        path += args[0];
        System.Console.WriteLine(path);
        StreamReader read_string = File.OpenText(path);
        string s = read_string.ReadToEnd();
        buffer_array = s.Split('\n');
    }
}
```

Edit: spelling

Comment: "It's like the < token skips the following entry" - exactly, it redirects standard input from the file specified after the `<`, and doesn't use that as a command-line argument. That's not an aspect of C# at all... it's just the way shells work. Unfortunately it's not at all clear to me what you *want* to happen, which makes it hard to help you.

Comment: The reason I am writing this program is its part of a test (finding the answer by any means available was the criteria), but the program will be tested by another program which will call the program with: test.exe < indata.txt. So I need to be able to handle this way of sending the arguments to pass the test. 

Edit: I want to read the data from the file after the "<" and it needs to be called as test.exe < indata.txt

Comment: Then you need to read from StdInput...

Comment: ^^ `Console.In.ReadToEnd()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following shows how to create a Console program that reads data from a filename that's been specified by one of the following:

1. redirecting input (`< infile.txt`)
2. specifying the filename using an argument (`-f:<filename>` or `-f:"<filename containing spaces>"`)
3. prompting the user for a filename if the filename wasn't specified

For usage, run the program with `/?` as the only argument.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filename = string.Empty;
        string[] buffer = null;
    
        if (Console.IsInputRedirected)
        {
            string data = Console.In.ReadToEnd();
            //Console.WriteLine(data);
    
            //set value
            buffer = data.Split('\n');
        }
        else if (args != null && args.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var arg in args)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("arg: " + arg);
    
                if (arg == "/?")
                {
                    Usage();
                }
                else if (arg.StartsWith("-f"))
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("arg: '" + arg + "'");
    
                    //set value
                    filename = arg.Substring(3).Trim();
    
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
                    {
                        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
                        {
                            Console.Error.WriteLine("Error: File '" + filename + "' doesn't exist.");
                            //return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //read data 
                            buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Error.WriteLine("Error: '-f' was specified, but filename wasn't specified (Note: No space is allowed between '-f:' and <filename>)");
                        //return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("Error: Argument '" + arg + "' unknown");
                    Usage();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter filename ('q' to quit): ");
                filename = Console.ReadLine();
    
                //remove double quotes
                filename = filename.Replace("\"", ""); 
    
                if (filename == "Q" || filename == "q")
                {
                    return;
                }
                else if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("Error: File '" + filename + "' doesn't exist.");
                }
                else
                {
                    //read data 
                    buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename);
                    break;
                }
            } while (true);
        }
    
        //display data
        DisplayData(buffer);
    }
    
    static void DisplayData(string[] buffer)
    {
        if (buffer != null)
        {
            foreach (string val in buffer)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(val);
            }
        }
    }
    
    static void Usage()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //string exeName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
        string exeName = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}Usage:{0}", System.Environment.NewLine);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0} -f:C:\\Temp\\Test1.txt{1}", exeName, System.Environment.NewLine);
        sb.AppendFormat("{0} -f:\"C:\\Temp\\Test 2.txt\"{1}", exeName, System.Environment.NewLine);
    
        Console.Write(sb.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the program is going to be called as you described (using the `< filename.txt` command line), the contents of the file will be available on STDIN.  Your code is what you would do if your program would be called with the filename as an argument.

You can use code like this to handle text on STDIN:

```
using System;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TextReader input = Console.In;
            String inpText = input.ReadToEnd();
            foreach(String line in inpText.Split('\n')) {
                Console.WriteLine("+++" + line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For an input like this:

```
This
Is
A
Multiline
Text File
```

Using `ConsoleApp1.exe < input.txt` you get:

```
+++This
+++Is
+++A
+++Multiline
+++Text File
+++
```